# Using evil and elscreen together

Tags: evil, elscreen

I just started using evil-mode after having used elscreen for a long time. evil-mode will bind the `C-z` key to `evil-emacs-state` but do you know how I can rebind either this function, or the elscreen emacs key?

Comment: Evil does not use elscreen in any way, so your whole question starts with a false premise.

Comment: @wasamasa, sorry I had the wrong information. From what I gather, there are extra packages to evil-mode which implement vim tabs using elscreen, but not part of evil-mode itself. I removed that sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have three options:

1- Change elscreen key prefix:

```
(setq elscreen-prefix-key "\C-.")
```

2- Manually override evil C-z binding:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z\C-c" 'elscreen-create)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-zc"    'elscreen-create)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-zC"    'elscreen-clone)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z\C-k" 'elscreen-kill)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-zk"    'elscreen-kill)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z\M-k" 'elscreen-kill-screen-and-buffers)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-zK"    'elscreen-kill-others)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z\C-p" 'elscreen-previous)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-zp"    'elscreen-previous)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z\C-n" 'elscreen-next)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-zn"    'elscreen-next)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z\C-a" 'elscreen-toggle)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-za"    'elscreen-toggle)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z'"    'elscreen-goto)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z\""   'elscreen-select-and-goto)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z0"    'elscreen-jump-0)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z1"    'elscreen-jump)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z2"    'elscreen-jump)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z3"    'elscreen-jump)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z4"    'elscreen-jump)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z5"    'elscreen-jump)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z6"    'elscreen-jump)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z7"    'elscreen-jump)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z8"    'elscreen-jump)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z9"    'elscreen-jump-9)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z\C-s" 'elscreen-swap)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z\C-w" 'elscreen-display-screen-name-list)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-zw"    'elscreen-display-screen-name-list)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z\C-m" 'elscreen-display-last-message)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-zm"    'elscreen-display-last-message)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z\C-t" 'elscreen-display-time)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-zt"    'elscreen-display-time)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-zA"    'elscreen-screen-nickname)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-zb"    'elscreen-find-and-goto-by-buffer)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z\C-f" 'elscreen-find-file)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z\C-r" 'elscreen-find-file-read-only)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-zd"    'elscreen-dired)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z\M-x" 'elscreen-execute-extended-command)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-zi"    'elscreen-toggle-display-screen-number)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-zT"    'elscreen-toggle-display-tab)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-z?"    'elscreen-help)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-zv"    'elscreen-display-version)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-zj"    'elscreen-link)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-zs"    'elscreen-split)
```

3 Make your custom bindings to evil, like:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "gt" 'elscreen-next)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "gT" 'elscreen-previous)
```